# Как в html поместить иконку SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, img

Не отображает иконку SVG. Если задать bacgkround-image, то иконка отображается (т.е. путь указан правильно). Как правильно прописать ее в HTML? Или кто подскажет другой способ? Иконку взяла с material design icons, в  Angular Material подходящей нет. Доступ по url иконки не подходит, она должна храниться локально

```html
    <button>
      <img src="../images/icons/arrow-decision-auto.svg">
    </button>
```

[image: Отображение иконки]

Код иконки

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="2em" height="2em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 5H9l4-4 4 4h-3v4.43a8.638 8.638 0 0 0-2 1.69V5zm-1.6 10H8.5l-.7-2H4.6l-.7 2H2l3.2-9h2l3.2 9zm-3.05-3.35L6.2 8l-1.15 3.65h2.3zM23 11l-4-4v3a6.75 6.75 0 0 0-7 6.17 3 3 0 1 0 2 0c.47-4 4.47-4.2 4.95-4.2v3L23 11z" /></svg>
```

Comment: код иконки добавьте и тогда можно будет более конкретно ответить

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, добавила ее название

Comment: Посмотрите в консоль. Есть ошибка типа `GET путь_к_иконке/arrow-decision-auto.svg 404 (Not Found)`?

Comment: @zhurof, да. есть такая ошибка

Comment: @new_user503  Если вам не подходит доступ к иконке с удаленного ресурса, скачайте её и добавьте код инлайн в HTML как указано в ответе ниже

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, так иконка скачена

Comment: А где и как вы задаёте background-image?

Comment: @new_user503 я тоже скачал иконку [arrow-decision-auto.svg](https://iconify.design/icon-sets/mdi/arrow-decision-auto.html) вызов  c помощью `<img>` работает. Иконку положил рядом с index.html Значит у вас что-то всё таки с путями

Comment: @new_user503 изменил в ответе примеры с кодом вашей иконки

Comment: Если у вас `html`-файл и папка `images` находятся на одном уровне вложенности (лежат непосредственно в одной папке), то в  `src` следует писать `images/адрес_иконки`, а не `../images/адрес_иконки`. Конструкция `../` означает подъём на один уровень вверх по каталогу.

Answer (score 3):

Добавил скаченную иконку на сервер и загрузил её в HTML с помощью `<img>`

```html
<button>
      <img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/arrow-decision-auto.svg">
 </button>
```

Значит у вас проблемы с путём до файла *.svg

Но в случае добавления  иконки с помощью `<img>` она ведёт себя как обыкновенное изображение, поэтому затруднительно сделать стилизацию обычными приемами с помощью CSS.

**Пока нет достаточного опыта работы с SVG, используйте инлайновый способ добавления иконки.**

Удалил из кода иконки `fill="#626262"` чтобы не мешало стилизации иконки

```css
.btn {
fill:dodgerblue;
transition:fill 0.5s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
fill:crimson;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="2em" height="2em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 5H9l4-4 4 4h-3v4.43a8.638 8.638 0 0 0-2 1.69V5zm-1.6 10H8.5l-.7-2H4.6l-.7 2H2l3.2-9h2l3.2 9zm-3.05-3.35L6.2 8l-1.15 3.65h2.3zM23 11l-4-4v3a6.75 6.75 0 0 0-7 6.17 3 3 0 1 0 2 0c.47-4 4.47-4.2 4.95-4.2v3L23 11z" /></svg>
</button>
```

**Ещё способ добавить svg иконки**

Данная техника подойдет, если нужно быстро добавить иконки в свой проект, которые можно раскрасить в любой цвет из внешнего файла `CSS`.
  Причём иконки высокого качества, практически полный набор на все случаи.
 Иконки адаптивны и не теряют качества при масштабировании, так как это иконки SVG из которых состоит символьный шрифт  - [**Google Material Icons**](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html)

Подключение шрифта:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)

Выбираем нужную иконку с именем - `favorite`

Подключение иконки к HTML странице:

`<i class="material-icons red">favorite</i>`, где

`material-icons` - общий класс для всех иконок
`red` - дополнительный класс, задающий цвет окраски иконки

Ниже пример с тремя одинаковыми иконками, которые раскрашены в разные цвета 
Добавлена анимация увеличения иконок при `hover`.

```css
.material-icons {
transform: scale(2);
}
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(4);
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:yellowgreen}
.blue{color: dodgerblue}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">        
<i class="material-icons red">favorite</i>
<i class="material-icons green">android</i> 
<i class="material-icons blue">backup</i>
```

Размер иконок также можно менять, здесь удвоенный исходный размер:

```
.material-icons {
transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, какое это имеет значение. В вашем примере можно стереть width и height и всё продолжает отлично работать

Comment: @andreymal это не имеет значения, потому что внутри самой svg иконке указаны `width="43" height="47"` В основном иконки идут без этих атрибутов, видимо у автора вопроса попалась именно такая иконка и если не указать размеры в этом случае, то иконка не отображается

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но тогда по идее background-image наверно тоже не должен был работать, но он работает

Comment: @andreymal нужен код от автора вопроса, а так остаётся только гадать

Answer (score 1):

> Если задать bacgkround-image, то иконка отображается (т.е. путь указан
>   правильно).

Если с путями к иконке всё действительно ОК, но не получается загрузить иконку svg с помощью `<img>`, то возможно у вас на локальном ПК или например: в Wordpress   не указан `MIME type` для svg ⇒  **image/svg+xml**

- Для `Wordpress` можно установить плагин, который всё сделает за вас и при этом не придется добавлять вручную `MIME type`, как описано ниже.
- Если плагин не помог или не хочется  использовать плагины, то можно
  добавить `MIME type` в ручную:

### 1. Добавляете в файл `functions.php`

```
function wpcontent_svg_mime_type( $mimes = array() ) {
  $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpcontent_svg_mime_type' );
```

Вы  заменяте `wpcontent_` своим собственным пространством имен. Эта функция просто добавляет SVG и SVGZ (сжатый SVG) к разрешенным типам загружаемых файлов в WordPress и подключается к функции WordPress `upload_mimes()`.

### 2. Добавление SVG Mime Types в .htaccess

Откройте ваш корневой файл .htaccess и добавьте следующее после строки: `#End WordPress`.

```
# Add SVG Mime Types
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Сохраните файл, и все готово! Теперь вы можете сохранять SVG из Illustrator или Inkscape и использовать их на своем сайте WordPress.

[Источник](http://www.wpcontent.co.uk/2014/09/enabling-and-using-svg-in-wordpress/)

Файл **.htaccess** обычно расположен в корне диска `C:` Если на вашем ПК его нет, то можно его скачать [здесь](http://www.novichkoff.ru/download-manager.php?id=40)

Вот содержание этого файла по умолчанию

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```